# Wordpress cURL works, but wp_remote_request does not

Tags: wordpress, php-curl

I have code which works using cURL but not using wp_remote_request.

The cURL code is:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$bc_auth_token
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

The wp_remote_request code is:

```
    $args = array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'sslverify' => false, 
    'headers' => array( 
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$bc_auth_token, 
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
    );
    
    $response = wp_remote_request($url, $args);
```

The cURL returns data as expected. The wp_remote_request returns the following:

```
(
[headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
    (
        [data:protected] => Array
            (
                [content-type] => application/xml
                [content-encoding] => gzip
                [vary] => Accept-Encoding
                [server] => Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
                [access-control-allow-headers] => Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization
                [access-control-allow-origin] => *
                [access-control-allow-credentials] => true
                [ms-correlation-x] => fc9da5c7-b168-4cbd-9246-68ac510a8b93
                [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
                [strict-transport-security] => max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
                [access-control-expose-headers] => ms-correlation-x
                [date] => Tue, 08 Jun 2021 23:31:43 GMT
            )

    )

[body] => <error xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata"><code>RequestDataInvalid</code><message>Request data is invalid.</message></error>
[response] => Array
    (
        [code] => 400
        [message] => Bad Request
    )

[cookies] => Array
    (
    )

[filename] => 
[http_response] => WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object
    (
        [response:protected] => Requests_Response Object
            (
                [body] => <error xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata"><code>RequestDataInvalid</code><message>Request data is invalid.</message></error>
                [raw] => HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
            )
    )    
(Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
ms-correlation-x: fc9da5c7-b168-4cbd-9246-68ac510a8b93
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ms-correlation-x
Date: Tue, 08 Jun 2021 23:31:43 GMT
Connection: close)
```

I have tried quite a few things but I cannot see any reason the wp_remote_request shouldn't work.

Does anyone have any insights?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same thing recently.

`wp_remote_request` adds a special User Agent to the request.
e.g. `"WordPress\\/6.2.2; http:\\/\\/your-site.com"`.

In my case, the external API would reject requests with that user agent.

I was able to set a different user agent for the request and sidestep this.

```php
wp_remote_request($url, [
  'user-agent' => null,
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$bc_auth_token, 
  ]
]);
```

This will make the `user-agent` empty.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* can you please below updated code where i have used wp_remote_get function instead of wp_remote_request function */    

     $args = array(
                'headers' => array(
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$bc_auth_token, 
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
                )
            );
        $url= "your URL";
        $response = wp_remote_get( $url, $args );

        $response = json_decode($response['body'], true);
```